# Laravel 4.2: Start a cron job after a month

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron, job-scheduling

I'd like to run a job that will reset a value of a column lets say to 0 in a database after a month then remove the job after that. How will I able to do this in Laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare a script to do the job (reset the value of a column). To run only once you can do this in your crontab:

```
30 12 16 10 ? 2015 /scripts/reset
```

This will execute your script at 12:30 on October 16th this year.

Anyway, your question has nothing to do with Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

I recommande you to use this awesome vendor

https://liebig.github.io/cron/

It's more efficient